# StageVideo problems

Tags: actionscript-3, stagevideo

i'm trying some examples founded on the web but don't works...
the code :

```
package{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.StageVideoAvailabilityEvent;
import flash.media.StageVideo;
import flash.events.StageVideoEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.media.StageVideoAvailability;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

public class myStageVideo extends Sprite{

    private var stageVideoAvail:Boolean;
    private var sv:StageVideo;

    public function myStageVideo(container:DisplayObjectContainer){
        container.addChild(this);
        container.addEventListener(StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY, onAvail);
    }

    private function onAvail(e:StageVideoAvailabilityEvent):void{
        trace("arrivato a onAvail");
        stageVideoAvail = (e.availability == StageVideoAvailability.AVAILABLE);
        initVideo();
    }

    private function initVideo():void{
        var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
        nc.connect(null);
        var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
        ns.client = this;
        stageVideoAvail = true;
        if(stageVideoAvail){
            sv = stage.stageVideos[0];
            sv.addEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, onRender);
            sv.attachNetStream(ns);
            trace('available');
        }
        else{
            var vid:Video = new Video(1024, 768);
            addChild(vid);
            vid.attachNetStream(ns);
            trace('not');
        }

        ns.play('video.mp4');
    }

    private function onRender(e:StageVideoEvent):void{
        sv.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    }

    public function onMetaData(e:Object):void{

    }

    public function onXMPData(e:Object):void{

    }
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong? I'm trying from a week, but nothing...
the video.mp4 is in the same folder.
i think 1 error 
It is the way in which I add the child to the container

Comment: Please describe what the actual problem is, and add any errors your recieving to the question (the error message, and line number it points to)

Comment: "but nothing." ... That does not help, what is your exact problem/error?